# Open or Close jQuery elements @ different screen sizes with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I have a web page (powered by jQuery, Bootstrap and a database) designed to hide articles on mobile devices, displaying only section headers styled as buttons. If a user clicks "Introduction," that particular section opens, revealing the text. The user also has the option of manually toggling any header to open or close it.

I'd like to modify it so that it works in reverse with larger screens; all the text should be displayed by default, though users can still manually toggle individual sections.

I know how to do that with a JS switch...

```
if( $(window).width() > 768 ) {
 // Scripts go here...
 } else {
}
```

I just wondered if there's also a way to do it with CSS, something like this...

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {    
 // Insert style that hides or reveals sections
}
```

This is an example of my HTML:

```
<section id="directions" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#directions2" class="SecCon">
  <h2><span class="label label-primary"><small><span class="only-collapsed glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><span class="only-expanded glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></small> Directions</span>  </h2>
  <div id="directions2" class="collapse in article">
    <p>Animals have the power of locomotion.</p>
  </div>
<section>
```

And these are the scripts that regulate closing and opening...

```
<script>
$('.collapse').collapse('hide').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $('section[data-target="#' + id + '"]').find('.only-expanded').show();
 $('section[data-target="#' + id + '"]').find('.only-collapsed').hide();

}).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $('section[data-target="#' + id + '"]').find('.only-expanded').hide();
 $('section[data-target="#' + id + '"]').find('.only-collapsed').show();
})
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what CSS style(s) I can use to make all the elements (sections) open at a larger screen size, while still allowing users to toggle each section open or closed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not one hundred percent sure that I understand the objective here, but if I'm thinking right, then Throwing a `display:none` or a `display:` [block|inline-block|whatever] in your media queries should do it. 
If you want a certain element to initialize hidden then `.show()` when selected (or vice versa) just do :

```
@media smaller screen {
    .collapsible_element {
        display:none;
    }
}

@media larger screen {
    .collapsible_element {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

and

```
<script>
    $('.collapsible_element')on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggle();
    });
</script>
```

You could also do it manually with `.show()` and `.hide()` but `.toggle()` is so clean.

Alternatively you could do something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle_title">
<label for="toggle_title">Title</label>
<p class="collapsible_element">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

and

```
#toggle_title { //hidden checkbox
    display:none;
}

label { //your clickable title
    //styles
}

.collapsible_element {
    height:0px; //just for kicks
    transition: height 2s; //to make things smooth
}

@media smaller screen {
    .collapsible_element {
        height:0px; //inits to 0
    }
    #toggle_title:checked ~ .collapsible_element {
        height:35px; //expands when title is clicked causing our hidden box to be checked
    }
}

@media larger screen {
    .collapsible_element {
        height:35px;
    }
    #toggle_title:checked ~ .collapsible_element {
        height:0px; //the opposite
    }
}
```

Which qualifies as you pure css version. It's fairly clean and I believe it's compatible enough to pass muster on the modern web (2 or 3 versions back). But that may not be wholly accurate.

You can see this effect in action on a website I built. It's working on the stylized radio buttons at the bottom of [the registration form](http://missiontrip.org/register).

**EDIT** And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L3df47bv/2/) in a beautiful fiddle that I made.

I apologize for not properly reworking your code but hopefully this illustrates my idea well enough.

Comment: Wow, you gave me a lot to think about. I'll play with some of your tips tonight. I don't want to mark it as the correct answer yet, but I probably will tomorrow. ;)

Comment: P.S. Regarding my objective, it works fine with the JS switch, but I'd just like to add to my options by learning how to do it with CSS as well. When I use the JS switch, I don't see any changes when I make my screen bigger or smaller (until I refresh the page). If I do it with CSS, I'll hopefully see the changes immediately; that would be helpful when I'm working on my pages.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Hope it helps out. Like I said. I'll see if I can provide a concrete snippit tonight.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom **That's** an excellent point. If you want things to happen when you resize then the CSS should work well. Of course there are ways to do that with JS and I would still [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) the css to check if it's compatible enough for your purposes but if you are looking to resize effectively the CSS could make it really sexy.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Dunno if that helps but I added a fiddle to illustrate things properly.